# Meteor/Handlebars #if not auto-updating

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I'm just getting started with Meteor, and I'm a little confused; I'm not sure if this is a Meteor issue or a Handlebars issue.

I'm trying to create a nested menu (a set of clickable divs, each of which toggles a submenu consisting of more clickable divs). I want the submenus to be hidden by default but appear when the user clicks their parent.

This is what I've got:

```
Template.sidebutton.events({
    click : function() {
        this.clicked = !this.clicked;
        clickHandlers[this.label]();
    }
})
```

and

```
<template name = "sidebutton">
    <div class = "sidebutton" id = "sidebutton_{{label}}"><p>{{label}}</p></div>
    {{#if clicked}}
        {{#each submenus}}
            {{> submenu}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

I've verified that the onclick function fires when I click; this.clicked is toggled and my click handlers are called. I've also verified that the submenus appear if I strip out the #if block or if I set clicked to true on the initial page load. But the submenus do not appear when I click.

Is there something more I need to do? Everything I find about Meteor seems to imply that if I change any of the data, affected objects are re-rendered, but it seems like they're not being re-rendered here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose "clicked" is in your mongodb db collection element, in this case, you cannot change its value like you do. You have to call somthing like that :

```
myCollection.update(_id, {clicked:!clicked});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not actually using the MongoDB yet; I was just initializing the button context as an array literal. In any case, it doesn't work, but I figured out how to do what I want with Session variables. Thank you!